How can I use the full potential of my CPU for the training process in ML.NET?
I'm currently trying to create a generator for place names, which I'm feeding with ~61k existing names to hopefully get some unique new ones. I think I got some of the basics done, but during training it only uses 60% of my CPU. I feel like I'm wasting some potential like that. Especially in the beginning where I have to adjust the training process a lot and re-run the process, always waiting ~6h (currently running on Ryzen 5 X7600, 12 logical cores) is a bit annoying.
I've set min number of threads already to 12, but that had no effect. The overall CPU utilization is not much higher than the 60%, so there are no CPU-hungry background processes. Is this by design? Could there be a limitation since I run it out of Visual Studio?

The data only consists of a CSV file with 1 column:
PlaceName
"Aabauerschaft"
"Aach"
"Aachen"
"Aach-Linz"
"Aalderink"
"Aalen"
"Aalkorb"
"Aasbuttel"
"Aasen"
"Aashausen"
"Abbecke"
"Abbehausen"
"Abbehauser Wehl"
"Abbehausergroden"

And so on. Each line is a string, which is put in double quotes since one name can have legit blank spaces, forward slashes, dashes and some other characters in the name.
Classes
public class PlaceNameData
{
    [LoadColumn(0)]
    public string PlaceName;
}

public class PlaceNamePrediction
{
    [ColumnName("PredictedLabel")]
    public string PredictedLabel { get; set; }
}

Code
string modelPath = Path.Combine(Directory.GetParent(System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()).Parent.Parent.FullName, "model.zip");
string modelPath2 = Path.Combine(Directory.GetParent(System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()).Parent.Parent.FullName, "model.bin");

ThreadPool.SetMinThreads(Environment.ProcessorCount, Environment.ProcessorCount);
var mlContext = new MLContext();
ITransformer trainedModel;

if (!File.Exists(modelPath))
{
    // Model doesn't exist yet, load data and train
    // Reading data from text file
    string path = Path.Combine(Directory.GetParent(System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()).Parent.Parent.FullName, "de2.csv");
    var data = mlContext.Data.LoadFromTextFile<PlaceNameData>(path, separatorChar: ',', hasHeader: true);
    Console.WriteLine("Data loaded");
    // Print schema for verification
    var preview = data.Preview();
    foreach (var column in preview.Schema)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"{column.Name} - {column.Type}");
    }
    // Normalizing data
    var pipeline = mlContext.Transforms.Text.NormalizeText("NormalizedText", "PlaceName")
                .Append(mlContext.Transforms.Conversion.MapValueToKey("Label", "PlaceName"))
                .Append(mlContext.Transforms.Text.TokenizeIntoWords("Tokens", "NormalizedText", separators: new[] { '\t', ',', ';' }))
                .Append(mlContext.Transforms.Conversion.MapValueToKey("Tokens"))
                .Append(mlContext.Transforms.Text.ProduceNgrams("Features", "Tokens"))
                .Append(mlContext.Transforms.NormalizeLpNorm("Features", "Features"));
    Console.WriteLine("Data normalized, training...");
    // Training
    var trainer = mlContext.MulticlassClassification.Trainers.OneVersusAll(
        mlContext.BinaryClassification.Trainers.SdcaLogisticRegression(labelColumnName: "Label", featureColumnName: "Features"),
        useProbabilities: false);
    var trainingPipeline = pipeline.Append(trainer)
        .Append(mlContext.Transforms.Conversion.MapKeyToValue("PredictedLabel", "Label")); // To map the prediction back to original label
    // Measure training time
    var watch = System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.StartNew();
    trainedModel = trainingPipeline.Fit(data);
    watch.Stop();
    var elapsedMs = watch.ElapsedMilliseconds;
    Console.WriteLine($"Training completed in {elapsedMs / 1000.0} seconds");
    // Save the model
    mlContext.Model.Save(trainedModel, data.Schema, modelPath);
    mlContext.Model.Save(trainedModel, data.Schema, modelPath2);
    Console.WriteLine($"Model saved to {modelPath}");
}
else
{
    // Read model from existing file
    trainedModel = mlContext.Model.Load(modelPath, out var modelInputSchema);
    Console.WriteLine("Existing model loaded");
    Console.WriteLine("Model Input Schema:");
    Console.WriteLine($"Input Schema: {modelInputSchema}");
}

// Print model properties
Console.WriteLine("Model Properties:");
Console.WriteLine($"Model Type: {trainedModel.GetType().FullName}");
Console.WriteLine($"Model Type: {trainedModel.ToString()}");
// Print model summary
Console.WriteLine("Model Summary:");
Console.WriteLine(trainedModel.ToString());
// Inspect the transformer chain
if (trainedModel is TransformerChain<ITransformer> transformerChain)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Transformer Chain:");
    var transformersField = transformerChain.GetType().GetField("_transformers", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
    var transformers = (ITransformer[])transformersField.GetValue(transformerChain);
    foreach (var transformer in transformers)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Transformer Type: {transformer.GetType().FullName}");
        Console.WriteLine($"Transformer Type: {transformer.ToString()}");
    }
}
// Prediction engine setup
var predictionEngine = mlContext.Model.CreatePredictionEngine<PlaceNameData, PlaceNamePrediction>(trainedModel);
// Example predictions
string[] inputExamples = new string[]
{
    "Aabauerschaft",
    "Aach",
    "Aachen",
    "Aach-Linz",
    "Aalderink",
    "Abbehauser Wehl"
};
foreach (var inputExample in inputExamples)
{
    var prediction = predictionEngine.Predict(new PlaceNameData { PlaceName = inputExample });
    Console.WriteLine($"Input: {inputExample}, Predicted place name: {prediction.PredictedLabel}");
}

Bonus questions:

Why are all predictions empty?

Update 1:
I did a "Release" build and executing that outside of VS appears to have an effect. It's almost at 80% now. I assume the debugging somehow interfered, but there is still some potential I think.

I'm not familiar at all with ML, but some minor notes: yes, "Release" build does improve performance - purpose of debug is fundamentally different.
Other point, if your program writes a lot to the console, that in itself might degrade the performance significantly (unfortunately, I can't tell from just looking, if you're writing just a couple line to the console or not).
Visual Studio gives the ability to check performance, hot paths and so on, so you can see what parts of code spend the most CPU time, so doing such a session might give you great input for identifying 'optimization spots'.
